Playwright - upload file by drag and drop
I need an help. When I am trying to upload file by function drag and drop, there is a one method that works for me:
async dopUpload(fileUploud: string): Promise<void>{
    const buffer = readFileSync(`./data_resources/${fileUploud}`);

    // Create the DataTransfer and File within the page context (more secure)
const dataTransfer = await this.page.evaluateHandle(async (buffer) => {
    const dt = new DataTransfer();
    const file = new File([buffer.toString('hex')], 'pop3.zip', { type: 'application/zip' });
    dt.items.add(file);
    return dt;
  }, buffer);

  // Dispatch the drop event for secure drag-and-drop simulation
  await this.page.dispatchEvent('body', 'drop', {
    dataTransfer,
    // Consider potential modifiers (e.g., shiftKey: true) if needed
  });

  await dataTransfer.dispose(); // Release the handle to avoid memory leaks

But Since I wan to use it also for another files, not just this one specifically I would like to pass the fileUpload parameter instead of 'pop3.zip'
But When I am putting the paramater fileUpload it always fails on
    Error: page.evaluateHandle: ReferenceError: filename is not defined at eval (eval at evaluate (:226:30), <anonymous>:3:55)"

Somebody any suggestion?

Can you share the actual site and a runnable [mcve]? It's hard to automate something I can't see. Thanks.
